# How to add click action when sending FCM notification from Node.js admin SDK to Flutter app?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a cloud function which executes this code to send the notification to the user, I am getting notification correctly but I want to navigate to a particular screen for that I have to add click action something like this.

`clickAction: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK`
I have tried to put this property in different lines of code but nothing seem to work, can someone please tell where should I put it exactly?
This is my index.js file!

```
const message = {
  token: data['guestFcmToken'],
  notification: {
    title: `New message from ${data['hostName']}.`,
    body: data['type'] === 'image' ? 'Photo' : data['lastMessage'],
  },
  data: {
    showForegroundNotification: 'false',
    screen: 'chat'
  },
}
console.log('Sending message');
const response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK' in the following way

```
message = {
    token: data['guestFcmToken'],
    notification: {
        title: `New message from ${data['hostName']}.`,
        body: data['type'] === 'image' ? 'Photo' : data['lastMessage'],
    },
    data: {
        showForegroundNotification: 'false',
        screen: 'chat'
    },
    android: {
        notification: {
            clickAction: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        },
    }
};
```